# Aptana Studio Terminal: Copy/Paste keyboard short cuts on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, aptana, aptana3

Anyone knows if there is an issue with Ctl+Shift+C and Ctl+Shift+V on Aptana Studio 3.x Terminal for copy/paste?

I am on Ubuntu 11.04 and I cant recall it ever working for me.

Is there any other short cut for copy/paste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried it on Ubuntu yet but I think there is a bug regardless of the OS. To get around this issue I found out that when you cut/paste between open applications ( ie: from notepad to Aptana, or Libre Office to Aptana) the paste sometimes stops working. However if you open Firefox, find any website with HTML text-box and paste your text there and then cut again from the HTML text-box and paste into Aptana then it works.

Make sure you do not submit the HTML text field :)

I love Aptana, at the end it outweights DW by far.

Comment: Thats weird indeed. Thanks for chiming in. Not a workflow that i would love to have for copy/paste :)  I have gotten used to working on Terminator + aptana. So I kinda forgot this issue existed :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set this keyboard shortcuts at Windows > Preferences > General > Keys, searching for copy and for paste. Copy each command and set the shortcut in Binding, i.e. Shift+Ctrl+V for Paste.

Comment: I don't know why this is not the accepted answer... Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Pressing Ctrl + Shift + V in Aptana on Ubuntu 15 (and earlier versions) would lock-up and freeze the entire Aptana editor and cause it to crash in the most annoying possible way with unsaved files and such.

To avoid this crashing I found that setting an unused key binding for Shift + Ctrl +V  , as juanolalla mentioned above, seems to catch those keystrokes and avoids the crash.

For some reason there are two "Paste" options in the "Keys" section so I just set one of them to Ctrl + V and the other to Shift + Ctrl + V and now my life is complete and my girlfriend doesn't have to listen to me flip my stuff at 1:30AM when I accidentally use a terminal-style paste inside of Aptana.